# Access Pgadmin4 in Production within dockerized django application

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm not sure how much sense it would make, but I was learning docker to deploy Django app with Gunicorn + Nginx + AWS.
So far, it works fine, where I have unit tested it in production.
My question is how can I access pgAdmin4 now?

`docker-compose.staging.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

# networks: 
#   public_network:
#     name: public_network
#     driver: bridge

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    # image: <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/django-ec2:web
    command: gunicorn djangotango.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      # - .:/home/app/web/
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media    
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging
    networks: 
      service_network:
 
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.staging.db
    networks: 
      service_network:
    # depends_on: 
    #   - web
  
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    env_file: 
      - ./.env.staging.db
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    depends_on: 
      - db
    links: 
      - "db:pgsql-server"
    environment: 
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=fakepassword
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
    networks: 
      service_network:

  nginx-proxy:
    build: nginx
    # image: <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/django-ec2:nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443  
      - 80:80
    networks: 
      service_network:
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media 
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy"
    depends_on:
      - web

  nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    env_file:
      - .env.staging.proxy-companion
    networks: 
      service_network:
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
  
networks: 
  service_network:
   
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  pgadmin-data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
```

I can access the django application through my domain name like xyz.example.com. I have just shown the docker-compose here.
Also within local I can access pgadmin4 via localhost:8080.

Is it possible to do it in production? If yes how?
I would be using AWS RDS for database, but for now my database is within docker container, so I'm thinking how to access it now?

Answer (score 1):

I found some documentation.

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/container_deployment.html

The url to access your pgadmin page would be configured in nginx. This example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/server.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /pgadmin4/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5050/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The important parts I am catching here are the location /pgadmin4/ redirecting to the localhost:5050. In your case, it would be localhost:8080.

It looks like in your other post you included your nginx config:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/no-live-upstream-while-connecting-to-upstream-jwilder-ngnix-proxy

```
upstream djangotango.meghaggarwal.com {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name djangotango.meghaggarwal.com

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://djangotango.meghaggarwal.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }

    location /static/ {
      alias /home/app/web/static/;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

        location /media/ {
        alias /home/app/web/media/;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

}

}
```

I would suggest adding a section like :

```
    location /pgadmin4/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

It might not be the only configuration you need to add... I have only skimmed the documentation. I am sure the link may help you more if this doesn't do the trick.